# Why can't I override the timeout on my Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am attempting to setup a CI Pipeline using Google Cloud Build.

I am attempting to deploy a MeteorJS app which has a lengthy build time - the default build timeout for GCB is 10 minutes and it was recommended [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/self-contained-dockerfile-for-deploying-meteor-apps/47949/3) that I increase the timeout.

I have setup my `cloudbuild.yaml` file with the `timeout` option increased to 20 minutes:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
timeout: 1200s
```

I have a Trigger setup in GCB connected to a Bitbucket Repo and when I push a change and the Trigger fires, I get 2 new builds - one coming from Bitbucket and one whose source is `Google Cloud Storage`.

Once 10 minutes of build time has elapsed, the build from Cloud Storage will timeout which will cause the Bitbucket build to fail as well with `Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`

Occasionally, for whatever reason, the Cloud Storage build will finish in under 10 minutes which will allow the Bitbucket build to finish successfully and deploy.

If I attempt to cancel/stop the Cloud Storage build, it will also stop the Bitbucket build.

The screenshot below shows 2 attempts of the exact same build with differing results.

[image]

I do not understand where this second Cloud Storage Build is coming from, but it does not seem to be affected by the settings in my yaml file or my global GCP settings.

I have attempted to run the following commands from the `gcloud` CLI:

```
gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1200
gcloud config set builds/timeout 1200
gcloud config set container/build-timeout 1200
```

I have also attempted to use a high CPU build machine to speed up the process but it did not seem to have any effect.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated - I feel that I have exhausted every possible combination of Google Search keywords I can think up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This timeout error comes from app engine deployment itself which has 10 min timeout by default.

You will need to update app/cloud_build_timeout property inside container itself like this:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1200 && gcloud app deploy']
timeout: 1200s
```

## Update

Actually simpler [solution](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine#configuring_the_deployment):

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
  timeout: 1200s
timeout: 1200s
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem with the Cloud Storage build - it completes every time now!

Comment: However, now the Bitbucket build is failing every time with the error: `INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: CPUS (quota: 8, used: 6 + needed: 4).` 

Any idea why this would be happening now?

Comment: You are hitting some CPU quota limit. Check [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) may be, under compute engine API-> CPUs. Anyways I don't understand why there are 2 builds running. I tried mirroring simple repo from bitbucket and after trigger only one build run with bitbucket as a source. I followed [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers#connecting_to_source_repositories). Are your 2 builds appear to do essentially the same in the end? Do you have 2 consecutive deployments in GAE versions tab?

Comment: This might happen due to you having GCP source repository mirroring bitbucket and similar trigger for it. So when you push to bitcbucket it gets mirrored to GCP repo and both triggers go off, one with cloud storage as a source and another with bitbucket. This is really excessive and consumes the quota I believe.

Comment: Thanks again for getting back to me Emil - do you think this Cloud Storage problem is a symptom of using Bitbucket or is there something I can do to prevent it from happening?

Comment: As @Emil Gi said, it seems that you have 2 separate builds for the same app, which should not be necessary. Did you set up the Build that uses Cloud Storage? Can you check the Cloud Build Triggers that you have and confirm whether the Cloud Storage Trigger is executing the same build as the BitBucket trigger or not?